# How to use combined CPU/Memory power of a Windows cluster

Tags: windows, hadoop, distributed-computing

I have 5 Windows machines (dual-core, 3GB) in a LAN all joined to a domain.

I have a program which needs 8-cores and 10 GB to run in a given SLA time.

What platform/tool can i use to harness the combined CPU/memory and other resources of these machines.

Hadoop ? Any other distributed computing platform ? But those will need me to re-design my program i want to run.

Any off-the-shelf tool which can help me create a larger computer of sorts withotu needing me to change my program code.

Answer (score 3):

Let me jsut say: cheaper to buy better boxes. No joke - 8 cores, 10g ram is a low end server.

There ARE 2 providers of "combined VM technology" but they are commercial and it COSTS. Like it is needed of you neded t o combine high end boxes. Single core license costs more than your outdated desktops combined, sadly.

So, the asnwer is: no way.

Check MOSIX for details if you want to know what is possible.

Comment: I agree. Sometimes adding hardware is the cheapest and best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is not already designed to run on a cluster, there is no way, except it has to solve a problem which can be separated into a group of real independent subtasks which each requires much less resources and can run on a single machine (think something like Folding@Home or Seti@Home).

Comment: Even for Hadoop , a lot of redesign will be needed, right ?

Comment: Yes, and it is entirely possible that Hadoop will not work at all for your problem set, which we don't know anything about. I agree with Tom: Buy a better box and be done with it.